# How do you change the cursor image?

Tags: java, cursor, lwjgl

I am coding a game in Java and I am wondering how one can change the appearence of the cursor to another design.
I am also using LWJGL and slick if that is any help for the people answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Custom and other system cursors**
You can create your own cursors (**Toolkit.createCustomCursor()**) or use cursors from the local system (**Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor(String)**).

You can change cursor type by setting the cusor property.Here are some types

Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR     **default cursor**
Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR  **crosshair cursor**
Cursor.HAND_CURSOR   **hand cursor**
Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR   **move cursor**
Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR   **wait cursor**
Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR   **text cursor**
Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR   **east-resize cursor**
Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR   **north-resize cursor**
Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR **north-east-resize cursor**
Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR **north-west-resize cursor**
Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR  **south-resize cursor**
Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR **south-east-resize cursor**
Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR **south-west-resize cursor**
Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR  **west-resize cursor**

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/misc/30cursor.html